# Подставить значение JS к URL

Tags: javascript, php, url

Есть следующий код:

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function lp_pixel_callback(tokens) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('device_name_1')[0].textContent = tokens.device_name;
    }
</script>

<p>
    Your device is <span class="device_name_1"></span>
</p>
```

Данный код выводит значение на странице:

Your device is Desktop

Т.е. ЗНАЧЕНИЕ = Desktop

1) Как это значение добавить к ссылке на странице?

```
<p><a href="http://site.ru/example/page1.php?a1=123&a2=ЗНАЧЕНИЕ"> Cсылка </a></p>
```

2) Как это значение добавить к ссылке, в которой уже реализована подстановка параметров через PHP?

```
<p><a href="<?echo 'https://site.ru/example/page1.php? a1='.$znachenie1.'&a2=ЗНАЧЕНИЕ';?>" Cсылка </a></p>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: 1) подставить переменную вместо `<p>` в `<a>` 2) Передать значение с клиента на сервер с помощью запроса

Comment: https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/docs.html можно заюзать готовое решение ну или самому парсить строку что тоже не слишком сложно

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц так я и не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы в ссылке это значение оказалось) Как сделать так, чтобы ссылка стала: `<a href="http://site.ru/example/page1.php?a1=123&a2=ЗНАЧЕНИЕ">` т.е. `<a href="http://site.ru/example/page1.php?a1=123&a2=Desktop">`  2) для меня вообще дебри. Я не программист, а начинающий маркетолог) Рассчитывал что это можно сделать путем вставки пары слов кода с правильным синтаксисом

Answer (score 2):

1. Элемент списка

***Привет*** Artemis.

Вообще вариантов много. Смотря что тебе проще будет.

1. Можно передать данные в js, потом через js вывести типа

```
var secval = "<?php echo $button; ?>";
```

а затем ссылку проставить в интерфейс через jquery или js. 
На подобии

```
<script language="JavaScript">
//Тут у Вас функция Ваша. В вопросе, Вы сообщили, что успешно получается вывести тип устройства (Эта функция не указана в вопросе, только функция проставления tokens.device_name в поле с классом device_name_1)
//Проще говоря в вопросе Вы пишите, что успешно проставляете тип устройства, но функция получения этого устройства не указана.
//Если у Вас данный код работал, то предполагается, что параметр tokens Вы получаете в других функциях, которые отсутствуют в вопросе.
// Если прям подробно, то функция lp_pixel_callback берёт параметр tokens, в котором содержится device_name.
//Если же у Вас не получается получить сам тип устройства, то это немного другой вопрос.
function lp_pixel_callback(tokens) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('device_name_1')[0].textContent = tokens.device_name;
    }
function secondval() {
    var znachenie2 = tokens.device_name;
    var secval = "<?php echo $znachenie1;?>" + znachenie2;
    alert(secval);
    return secval;
}
</script>
<p> hm <a href="<script>document.write(secondval())</script>">"<script>document.write(secondval())</script>"</a></p>
```

2. Можно воспользоваться инструментами jquery или java.
3. Так же можно обрабатывать параметр или подменять его уже при нажатии через

```
//var znachenie2 = '123';
location.href = "<?php echo 'https://site.ru/example/page1.php? a1='.$znachenie1.'&a2=';?> + tokens.device_name";
```

4. Можно использовать инверсионный вариант от первого предложенного в совокупности с третим

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>640kb</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function lp_pixel_callback(tokens) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('device_name_1')[0].textContent = tokens.device_name;
    }
        window.onload = function(){
            var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), i = a.length;
            while(i--){
                a[i].onclick = (function(){
                    return function(){
                        var znachenie2 = tokens.device_name;
                        this.href = this.href + znachenie2;
                        alert(this.href);
                        return false;
                    };
                })();
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p><a class="123" href="<?php echo 'https://site.ru/example/page1.php? a1=' . $znachenie1 . '&a2='; ?>"> Cсылка </a></p>
</body>
```

5. Использовать GET и POST запросы js.

Так что подбирай вариант, который тебе более понятен и комфортен и дерзай )
Удачи!

Comment: Denis, спасибо большое! Но я все равно не понял) Как мне это значение "Desktop" из span присвоить переменной JS(Либo присвоить PHP $znachenie2, чтобы потом подставить в ссылку по аналогии с $znachenie1), в своих примерах Вы сами назначаете значение переменной.

Comment: @Artemis, у Вас в javascript есть функция  <br>   function lp_pixel_callback(tokens) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('device_name_1')[0].textContent = tokens.device_name;
    }
<br>

В этой функции у Вас как раз проставляется параметр tokens.device_name в нужное место. 
Вам надо заменить в моих примерах znachenie2 на tokens.device_name.
Сейчас напишу

Comment: Подскажите тогда, какую библиотеку определения девайса Вы используете?

Comment: Я на самом деле хотел изначально написать упрощенно, думал подобные вопросы не возникнут. Код джаваскрипт и подстановка значения в span это код от трекера. На данной странице, в самом начале стоит код пикселя от этого трекера. Поэтому эта библиотека, которую использует трекер, но какая именно не знаю.

Comment: А как называется файл js? Попробуем по названию найти. 
Есть как jquery так и js библиотеки по получению типа устройства и размерам экрана.

Comment: Думаю, что это не имеет значение. Трекер может передавать разные значения, в том числе, которые генерируется в нем самом, например clickid или номер компании или оффера. В этом случае, в коде <script type='text/javascript'>
    function lp_pixel_callback(tokens) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('device_name_1')[0].textContent = tokens.device_name;
    }
</script> нужно device_name заменить на clickid и или offerid и он уже будет передавать другие значения. Вообще в ссылку мне нужно подставить несколько значений, но начать я решил с подстановки одного)